# Passing function expression to object returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have reviewed similar questions and most seem to concern `this`, mine doesn't. I am trying to create a new `property` that is a `function expression` on objects in an array but the `property` returns undefined. I need it to return `function`

Here is a [fiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/0ftbqroe/2/).

```js
let athleteArray = [
  rupert = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: '33',
    sport: 'sitting',
    quote: 'Hello Super nintendo chalmers'
  },

  alice = {
    name: 'Bill',
    age: '35',
    sport: 'cooking',
    quote: 'stop that'
  }
];


const win = function(name, sport) {
  console.log(`${name} won the ${sport} event!`)
}

//loop to add new 'win' property

for (let i = 0; i < athleteArray.length; i++) {
  athleteArray[i].win = win(athleteArray[i].name,
    athleteArray[i].sport)
  console.log(athleteArray[i])
  console.log(typeof(athleteArray[i].win))
}
```

Comment: So, you want the athleteArray[i] to be a function returned from win? You are only doing a console.log and not returning anything with win so you are getting undefined on it and the typeof undefined is undefined as well

Comment: You should just use a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class where you can define your methods.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(details) {
     this.name = details.name || 'Unknown';
     this.age = details.age || 'Unknown';
     this.sport = details.sport || 'Unknown';
     this.quote = details.quote || 'Unknown';
  }
  win () {
    return `${this.name} won the ${this.sport} event!`;
  }
}

const athleteArray = [
  new Person({
    name: 'Mike',
    age: '33',
    sport: 'sitting',
    quote: 'Hello Super nintendo chalmers'
  }),

  new Person({
    name: 'Bill',
    age: '35',
    sport: 'cooking',
    quote: 'stop that'
  })
];

athleteArray.forEach(person => console.log(person.win()));
```

If you want to do it your way, you need to create a function. You just assign what it returns to the property

```js
let athleteArray = [
  rupert = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: '33',
    sport: 'sitting',
    quote: 'Hello Super nintendo chalmers'
  },

  alice = {
    name: 'Bill',
    age: '35',
    sport: 'cooking',
    quote: 'stop that'
  }
];


const win = function(name, sport) {
  console.log(`${name} won the ${sport} event!`)
}

//loop to add new 'win' property

for (let i = 0; i < athleteArray.length; i++) {
  athleteArray[i].win = () => win(athleteArray[i].name,
    athleteArray[i].sport)
  console.log(athleteArray[i])
  console.log(typeof athleteArray[i].win)
  athleteArray[i].win();
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference (beside the syntax) of the rewritten property assignment in the second option you provided: ``athleteArray[i].win = () => win(athleteArray[i].name, athleteArray[i].sport)`` and what I had?

Comment: `athleteArray[i].win = function () { return win(athleteArray[i].name, athleteArray[i].sport); }`

Answer (score 1):

You have to return something from the win function:

```js
let athleteArray = [
  rupert = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: '33',
    sport: 'sitting',
    quote: 'Hello Super nintendo chalmers'
  },

  alice = {
    name: 'Bill',
    age: '35',
    sport: 'cooking',
    quote: 'stop that'
  }
];


const win = function(name, sport) {
  return `${name} won the ${sport} event!`;
}

//loop to add new 'win' property

for (let i = 0; i < athleteArray.length; i++) {
  athleteArray[i].win = win(athleteArray[i].name,
    athleteArray[i].sport)
  console.log(athleteArray[i])
  console.log(typeof athleteArray[i].win )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'win' function does not return anything. The way you wrote the code, 'athleteArray[i].win' will be undefined. To do what you want, you should do something like that:

```
  athleteArray[i].win = () => win(athleteArray[i].name, athleteArray[i].sport)
```

It's easier to understand the error if the code were like that:

```
const returnedValue = win(athleteArray[i].name,  athleteArray[i].sport)

// Returned value is undefined
athleteArray[i].win = returnedValue
```